# "Authentication failed" when trying to upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade

I get the following error message when trying a network upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10:

> authentication failed. authenticating the upgrade failed. there may be
>   a problem with the network or with the server

I googled that error and found one proposed solution:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 437D05B5

gpg --export --armor 437D05B5 | apt-key add -
```

However, this seems to have screwed up at least [one guy's system](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/drves/i_am_having_trouble_upgrading_from_lucid_to/).

Is there any safer way of solving this (besides doing a fresh install)?

Comment: R u behind proxy.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: I forgot about this question! The suggested answer did not do anything. After several tries I found a workaround - I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not solve this directly, but found a workaround: I put the latest Ubuntu (11.10) on a USB stick, booted to USB, and selected 'upgrade Ubuntu' from the options. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I started ubuntu manager from the terminal to find the error. The problem was that /etc/apt/trusted.gpg could not be read.

```
sudo chmod +r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
```

fixed the problem.